# how can I mass delete attachment files on a case record?

Tags: administration, delete

I have a case (and many otheres) that hold the image file of the email header that is attached to the case. Therefore, on a busy case, one with many emails attached via email to case, there can be close to a hundred image file attachments. Is it possible to mass delete these files in one go?

Comment: are they identifiable in a way you could select them through anonymous apex ? That's how I often quick delete data in sandboxes (or play-around-production-orgs). If functional you can schedule it.

Comment: worth me looking at.

Comment: If you have a reliable way of identifying such attachments; you could use an after insert trigger on Attachment that executed a future method that in turn deleted the Attachment